# Why doesn't my code evaluate element of a vector at a given t?

Tags: differential-equations, vector

I have written a code to solve the Shrodinger equation for a particular three level siystem in two ways: the first way I defined three functions C1[t], C2[t], C3[t] and I solved three ODEs;

[image]

the second way I defined a vector Cn[t_]:={C1[t],C2[t],C3[t]} and solved a single equation.

[image]

My code needs to evaluate, at the final time t0, the value of (Abs[C3[t0]])^2. This task is easily accomplished in the first code:

[image]

but not in the second, where the output doesn't give me the numerical value:

[image]

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Here's the code that gave me problems:

```
\[CapitalDelta] = 0
\[Gamma] = 0
\[Delta] = 0
T = 100
\[CapitalOmega] = 1
t0 = 5*T
\[Tau] = 0.7*T
\[CapitalOmega]s[t_] := \[CapitalOmega]*Exp[-((t + \[Tau])/T)^2]
\[CapitalOmega]p[t_] := \[CapitalOmega]*Exp[-((t - \[Tau])/T)^2]

H[t_] := (1/2)*{{0, \[CapitalOmega]p[t], 0}, {\[CapitalOmega]p[t], 2*\ 
[CapitalDelta] - I*\[Gamma], \[CapitalOmega]s[t]}, {0, \ 
[CapitalOmega]s[t], 2*\[Delta]}}
Cn[t_] := {C1[t], C2[t], C3[t]}

s = NDSolve[{D[Cn[t], t] == (1/I)*H[t] . Cn[t], Cn[-t0] == {1, 0, 0}}, 
Cn[t], {t, -t0, t0}]
Evaluate[Abs[C3[t0]]^2 /. s]
```

Comment: Please include the actual Mathematica code in  your question, not a picture of it.  Also, provide the complete code, including  values of constants.

Comment: My first thought is that the use of uppercase `C` is reserved. While you are preparing to paste your code, please switch to lowercase symbol names.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried to past the code (Using https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site this guide) but it kept looking bad and unformatted, so I thought it could be better to include a picture of it.
For what it's worth,I'm sure both codes work because at the end of both I plotted (Abs[C3[t]])^2 which gives me the correct result in both cases.
So the only problem seems to be in that last command..

Comment: In the second bit of code, it spits out a replacement rule for `C3[t]`, whereas in the first it spits out a replacement rule for `C3`. The first then works because in the replacement `Abs[C3[t0]]^2 /. s`, it matches the pattern for `C3`, but in the second, it matches the pattern for `C3[t]`, and nothing in `Abs[C3[t0]]^2 /. s` matches `C3[t]`.  Instead, do `Abs[C3[t]]^2 /. s /. t -> t0`.

Comment: In such a case, if you feel the pictures of the code make it significantly easier to read, please *also* provide the (input) code itself alongside those pictures—this allows people to easily copy-paste and test out your code (and test modifications to it) without re-typing it all themselves.

Comment: @march Thanks very much, it worked!

Comment: @thorimur You're right. I already got a useful answer to this question, but I will surely keep this in mind for the next question, thank you very much

Comment: Sara, there’s no answer to this question, yet (SE displays 0 answers). I would recommend putting your code in your question here as an update, then perhaps providing a self-answer using march’s suggestion that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @march, the problem was that the second bit of code spit out a replacement rule for C3[t] instead of C3; Substituting what I initially wrote with `Abs[C3[t]]^2 /. s /. t -> t0` solved the problem.